# What are the components and quasicomponents?

Tags: general-topology, definition

I'm trying to understand the difference between components and quasicomponents. I'm using the following definitions:

> $x\sim y$ iff $x$ and $y$ lie together  in some connected set. The **component of** $x$ is the equivalence class of $x$, $C_x:=[x]_{\sim}$
>   
> $x\approx y$ iff there is no decomposition into disjoint open sets, one containing $x$ and other containing $y$. The **quasicomponent of** $x$ is the equivalence class of $x$, $QC_x:=[x]_{\approx}$

I can see that the component is the biggest connected set that contains $x$, and that it is a closed set, but I'm not sure what quasicomponents are. I was thinking that perhaps the definition could be seen as "$x\approx y$ iff $x,y\in U,\;\forall U\in\tau$ ", that way is clear that in general $C_x\not=QC_x$, and that $QC_x$ are open and $C_x\subset QC_x$, although that last one might not be as clear.

Am I right? Where can I find examples of this?

Comment: It’s not hard to show that the quasicomponent of $x$ is the intersection of all clopen sets containing $x$; that’s a fairly nice, concrete way to think about it. This implies that each quasicomponent of a space is a union of components. It’s a theorem that in compact Hausdorff spaces each quasicomponent *is* a component.

Comment: Oh, and the quasicomponent of a point need not be open, though it will always be closed: the quasicomponents of the Cantor set $C$ are the singletons $\{x\}$ for $x\in C$.